# Prototype - Are there AJAX start/stop events to global trigger an AJAX modal wait message?

Tags: prototype

In Prototype, are there AJAX start/stop events that would allow you to create one script for globally displaying a modal wait message during AJAX loads?

Like, with jQuery I'm using this one script in the application layout to globally display a modal wait dialog for any jQuery AJAX events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="../images/busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $.unblockUI();
});
</script>
```

Thanks - much appreciated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Prototype you have access to a variable `Ajax.activeRequestCount` ([more info here](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/responders))

> This contains, at any time, the amount
>   of currently active AJAX requests
>   (those created by Prototype, anyway),
>   by monitoring their onCreate and
>   onComplete events

**EDIT**

Untested but something like this should work:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: showProcessing,
  onComplete: hideProcessing
});

function showProcessing() {
  if(Ajax.activeRequestCount > 0){
        $('inProgress').show();
    }
}

function hideProcessing () {
  if(Ajax.activeRequestCount <= 0){
      $('inProgress').hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: cool thanks - you wouldn't know of an example for monitoring that?   Would it just be having a funtion running contantly checking for > 1 to display the wait and < 1 to clear the wait?  Thanks!