# How to translate Protoype "Ajax.Responders.register" to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I have to translate some prototype code to jquery and and I don't know how to translate this part :

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: function() {
    $('working').show();
    window.onbeforeunload = check_working;
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    $('working').hide();
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  }
});
```

In fact I found some pages which deal with this problem ([Prototype - Are there AJAX start/stop events to global trigger an AJAX modal wait message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291057/prototype-are-there-ajax-start-stop-events-to-global-trigger-an-ajax-modal-wai) for instance) but I did this :

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  jQuery('#working').show();
  window.onbeforeunload = check_working;
});
jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function() {
  jQuery('#working').hide();
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

And I don't know why but I never enter into the ajax.start and stop (I tried with console.log by doing the same things that I did with the previous version which works). And I have no error.

Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/): *As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSend() method should only be attached to document*

Comment: Sorry my post was incorrect I used jQuery(document).ajax...